# How to locate the code location that causes the application to receive SIGTTIN under linux?

Tags: c, linux

One of my c++ applications will hang after running for an indeterminate length of time, because it is not terminated, so it cannot be restarted by the parent process.

It is known that SIGTTIN can prevent the program from being suspended by `nohup` or by using `</dev/null` to redirect standard input, but this does not solve the problem fundamentally.

So, does anyone know how to debug or locate the location of the code that produces the SIGTTIN signal?

```c
// this is a example, exec command to get SIGTTIN: ./a.out &
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        int len;
        char buf[64];

        while(1) {
                len = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 64);
                if (len > 0) {
                        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, len);
                }
                else {
                        perror("read");
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: so what should happen there? it is reading from `stdin` but there is no `stdin` to read from!? Ignore `SIGTTIN` and get an error from `read` instead, and spam the screen full of `read: Input/output error`?! Stop reading from `stdin`.

Answer (score 3):

You launch your program in background doing `./a.out &` but your program reads from *stdin* so you have that signal

From https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html :

> Macro: int SIGTTIN
>
> A process cannot read from the user’s terminal while it is running as a background job. When any process in a background job tries to read from the terminal, all of the processes in the job are sent a SIGTTIN signal. The default action for this signal is to stop the process. For more information about how this interacts with the terminal driver, see Access to the Terminal.
>
> locate the location of the code that produces the SIGTTIN signal?

It is the *read*

Answer (score 0):

#### Thank everyone for your reply. The problem has been solved.

Sometimes I know the reason for SIGTTIN, but I can't locate the code that caused the error. For example, the program does not directly use `scanf, read(0, ...), cin, ...` system calls or library functions, which are more prominent when the program is larger or when using multiple threads.

#### Here's how to locate the code location that causes SIGTTIN:

- Use ps to query the pid of your program (if you need to debug the thread, you can use `ps -eLf` to get tid).
- Use `strace -p $(YOUR PID) -e read` to track the system call of the program. If necessary, add the `-v` option. If you want to track the process and all its sub-threads to locate the code, use  `Strace -fp $(YOUR PID) -e read`.When the program is executed in the background, all `read(0, ..., ...)` calls may cause SIGTTIN. According to the parameters or return values of `read(0, ..., ...)`, the corresponding code can be found position.